# Does references between entities of the same aggregate hurt the Aggregate Pattern from DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, orm, aggregate

Consider an application being implemented following Domain Driven Design.

In the same aggregation, there are `Car` and `Computer` entities that should have a `one to many` relationship between them (`Car` has one `Computer` and `Computer` can be embedded in many of `Car`). They are in the same aggregation because `Computer` only exists within `Car`, so the `Car` is the aggregation root. Below, some simplified pseudo code.

The application uses for persistence an orm that requires such entities to have explicit relationship configuration between them using  **references** and **back references** such as `Computer computer` and `Car[] cars`.

Does the usage of these references between the classes on the same aggregation root hurt the aggregate pattern principle from domain driven design? In time, the only reason why `Computer` have an identifier, is because these entities will be persisted in different tables on the database.

```
class Car
  uuid id
  string name
  string color

  # Here is the reference
  uuid computer_id   
  Computer computer
```

```
class Computer
  uuid id
  string processor
  int memory
  int storage

  # Here is the back reference
  Car[] cars
```

Comment: P.S.: I've abstracted as much as possible the technologies involved on the implementation of this system because the question goal is to get a conceptual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question: "Does the usage of these references between the classes on the same aggregation root hurt the aggregate pattern principle from domain driven design?". No. This is the intention of aggregate. One of the entity should be able to refer other entity in the same aggregate.

When you are doing DDD, aggregates are transactional boundary. And when you are persisting the entities in a normalized form in a database it could be hard to make aggregates as transactional boundary. To make aggregates as your transactional boundary, you would have to implement a lot of event store logic. Instead, I would prefer to use a [event store] (https://eventstore.org/), or (if using c#) use a library such as [SqlStreamStore](https://sqlstreamstore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [NEventStore](http://neventstore.org/).

Or when none of these are feasible to me I would store the aggregate in serialized form along with aggregate version and aggregate id. With this it would relatively easy for me to build transactional boundary around an aggregate.

To answer in short, I would not choose to use a ORM and persist aggregates in normalized form because enforcing transactional boundary is difficult. For me this is the only issue and nothing else

Comment: Nachiappan, thank you for your answer! The intent is really to prevent the domain from being modeled just to resolve technological matters, so we will take a look and research on the event store suggestion. In time, the provided alternative of storing the relation as a serialized json-ish column is also good for our scenario, we actually do that in another aggregate, since our dbms have great support for it.

Answer (score 0):

> In the same aggregation root, there are Car and Computer

I think this is where you are going wrong.

In your example `Computer` is the Aggregate Root. You can only have one 'root' object per aggregate.

If you think of things this way around your object graph just becomes a standard parent-child tree where you need to load all the objects in order to keep calculated properties on the parent valid.

Having a child reference its parent like you have is fine as long as you are happy to load the entire graph when you need a single car.

Otherwise it would be better to simply have the the computerId property as a cross aggregate link

Comment: Ewan, the entire graph loading is actually a desired behaviour for this system, it will be lazily loaded as required, so if it doesn't hurt the aggregation, we are fine with it, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: In time, just for clarifying, in the example, the `Car` is indeed the only aggregation root and `Computer` only exists within the `Car` :)

Comment: Fixed the question, you are correct, it should be "Car is the aggregation root" and "Car and Computer are in the same aggregate" ;)

Comment: @danieldeveloper001 Computer is the AR

Comment: Ewan, sorry, could you please elaborate? The main entity for this aggregate is Car and the entity which is supposed to depend upon other to exist is Computer. Why would Computer be the aggregation root? Many thanks!

Comment: because the computer is the parent object. car is a child object. if you load a car you have to load a computer which has to load all cars. so computer is the root